# Python: mechanize don't find any form

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I'm trying to login to a website with mechanize. The weibsite hasn't a form. Could someone please help me? What is the problem?
Thank you

Python Code:

```
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("http://website.com/login.php")

print "forms-start"
for form in browser.forms():
    print form
print "forms-end"
```

Outut:

```
forms-start
forms-end
```

Website:

```
<body>
<div align="center">
    <div class="msg"></div><br/>
    <form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
        <p><span><b>Username*:</b></span>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="your account name" value="" style="width:18em" /></p>
        <p><span><b>Password*:</b></span>&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="your account password" value="" style="width:18.0em" /></p>
                    <p><span><b>Remember*:</b></span>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" checked/></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="1" />
        <input type="submit" class="frmbtn" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does :
from mechanize import Browser
browser = Browser()
response = browser.open("http://website.com/login.php")
print response.code
say?

Comment: Ok so the website is there answering. if you exchange .code with .read() you should get the output that mechanize sees, could you post this too?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3wLDPHKZ

Comment: Ok this looks good too. But why doesn't mechanize recognize the form...

Comment: That's my question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html) Mechanize cant handle invalid HTML

like :" br/ "
you have such code on your [website](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3wLDPHKZ)

You could use the BeautifullSoup Parser

```
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
browser.open("http://example.com/")
print browser.forms
```

Alternatively, you can process the HTML (and headers) arbitrarily:

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("http://example.com/")
html = browser.response().get_data().replace("<br/>", "<br />")
response = mechanize.make_response(
    html, [("Content-Type", "text/html")],
 "http://example.com/", 200, "OK")
browser.set_response(response)
```

From the FAQ